# Elementary Java Code Explanation

Tags: java

Kinda shameful to ask, because after many years of Java coding, i have never used this style of coding and i seem to come across it every time but this time please i'd better learn it once and for all.
Here is the code snippet:

```
private int batchSize;
private int firstRecord;
private int recordCount;

public int getLastRecord() {

    return firstRecord + batchSize > recordCount ? recordCount : firstRecord + batchSize;
}
```

Can anyone please explain what this method will return for different values of the parameters or point me to tutorial that can explain this to me. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: After years of Java coding you should know how to look up basic syntax or just write an example. It's also a poorly-named function, which doesn't help understand it either.

Comment: This is a bad way of writing `return Math.min(recordCount, firstRecord + batchSize);`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a ternary expression (in Java, it is officially called the [Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)) and it means

```
if (firstRecord + batchSize > recordCount) {
   return recordCount;
} else {
   return firstRecord + batchSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldnt search 'cos didnt know its called "ternary expression".

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing different value of `firstRecord` , `batchSize` and `recordCount`

It first execute `firstRecord + batchSize > recordCount` evaluate `(firstRecord + batchSize)` value.

If `firstRecord + batchSize` value is greater then `recordCount` it will return `recordCount` else return `firstRecord + batchSize` value

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your're using a ternary operator in getLastRecord function.

Ternary Operator: variable x = (expression) ? value if true : value if false

Following is the example:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]){
      int a , b;
      a = 10;
      b = (a == 1) ? 20: 30;
      System.out.println( "Value of b is : " +  b );

      b = (a == 10) ? 20: 30;
      System.out.println( "Value of b is : " + b );
   }
}
```

This would produce the following result:

```
Value of b is : 30
Value of b is : 20
```

Refer: [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)